# An easy-to-use sqlite3 wrapper

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

Is there any sqlite3 wrapper for python that actually makes working with database short and easy?
An ideal API would use native python objects comfortably (say when returning a row from a table, it would return it as a dictionary with the keys being the column names) and would hand the SQL command string formatting if possible.

Comment: You are searching for an ORM, but software recommendations are off topic here, and with an ORM, you will eventually run into [problems](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/).

Comment: and what about the build-in one [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)? you can use the the `row_factory` attribute to return a `dict` as show in the documentation and it handle SQL string formating

Comment: @Copperfield EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so much. `conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`, this simple line solved all my problems :D